# ¿Cómo poner mapas openlayers, en el administrador de django?

Tags: django, openlayers

No puedo visualizar el mapa de openlayers que pone por defecto el admin de django

Comment: ¿Cómo lo haces en una página _"normal"? ¿Necesitas algún JavaScript para visualizarlos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En admin.py de la app, define la url de origen de open layer

```
    from django.contrib.gis import admin

    class CapaAdmin(admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
        openlayers_url = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/OpenLayers.js"
```